# Adding documentation to spyder (python IDE)

Tags: python, documentation, installation, pygame, spyder

So I've been working with the pygame library (in spyder) lately, but I don't have the documentation installed like the built-in library. I've looked around but haven't seen a how-to on getting the pygame documentation or installing it.

Is there a pygame documentation? If so, how do I install it such that I don't have to google the syntax everytime I forget it? If you know, thanks in advance!

The documentation is something that shows the options when you type math. or numpy. like [so](http://c.oppy.me/CTByXY4J.png) as well as the syntax and brief explanation like [so](http://c.oppy.me/MMT32LgC.png) when you use different functions.

*Note that I have pygame installed, it runs smoothly (executing in a dedicated python interpreter as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) I guess you are trying to consult the documentation from the Editor, right? If that's the case, I have to let you know that it's not possible for us to extract documentation for *all* Python modules, because of some technical limitations of the libraries we use to do it. The most problematic modules are the ones built with C extensions, like (precisely) Pygame or OpenCV.

We are aware of this situation and are working to solve it in a future release (planned at the moment for `2.3.1`, to be released in August) by using a library called `jedi`.

You can also use the console (either Python or IPython) to obtain the docs. That's the best we can offer you for now :-)

Comment: I think you can mark it as answered by using the green check sign :)

Comment: im using 2.3.4 but i still dont see how to get documentation for a function - whats the command ?

Comment: @j2emanue, unfortunately not all documentation can be retrieved. The command is `Ctrl+I`. What function are trying to get documentation for?