# Access OpenCV documentation in spyder

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

I have *Python 2.7.9* and *OpenCV 3.1.0* installed on a Windows System. I'm using *Spyder 2.3.2* and would love to access documentation for OpenCV in the IDE, however using `Ctrl+I` on `cv2` functions/objects only shows `No documentation available`.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307822/adding-documentation-to-spyder-python-ide/24388458#24388458), OpenCV documentation should be available since *Spyder 2.3.1*.

Do I need to install additional modules, copy some files or update packages? If I need to upgrade Spyder, how do I do that? (it seems to be part of my pythonxy installation and the python setup on windows often seems so fragile that I'm hesitant to mess around with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Jedi in Spyder was added in Spyder **2.3.3**, released more than two years ago. Jedi is the library used to get completions and documentation from compiled modules like OpenCV.

The latest Spyder version is **3.1.0**, which has better integration with Jedi, so I recommend you to update to that version instead.

However, I don't know how to do it using PythonXY, sorry. You should use the Anaconda distribution instead, which is more up to date than PythonXY.

Comment: Thank you! I actually ended up using Anaconda indeed.